# Public-facing SharePoint 2007 portal - authentication question

Tags: sharepoint-2007, forms-authentication

I am involved in developing a portal with a public-facing side. For this i created a web application with windows authentication for intranet zone and after that, I created an extension for an internet zone with fba. In the internet extension we have the following requirement:
- able to acess to sharepoint backoffice using fba.
- have a authentication mecanism for portal visitors, where they can authenticate and acess to a page where they can subscribe the newsletter and define some site appearance (this users can't acess to sharepoint backoffice).
My idea is use the aspnet membership provider to authenticate both users and create diferente roles for them. Anyone suggests another approach? Is there any way to ensure that visitors (2 case) do not enter the backoffice portal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to achieve what you want through permissions and FBA. You can great a couple of security groups, one for guest visitors, one for 'backoffice' visitors.

Assign the guests group permission to see the public section of the site, and the backoffice visitors can get permission to see the backoffice section.